# Update Cell If another cell is not empty - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are two columns N and O.

[image]

When any cell in column **N** is filled the adjoining cell in column **O** needs to filled with "**Yes**" if not it stays empty.

This is the script I'm using.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "Sheet 1" ) 
    {
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
           if( r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == '') 
           {
              var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
                  nextCell.setValue("YES");
           }
    }
```

How can I change/modify the above script to show if when a cell is filled in a particular column then the adjoining cell shows as "Yes"

Or simply put translate this formula into a script

```
=if(ISBLANK(N2),"","Yes")
```

Without using it in this form

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("C2:C1000");
cell.setFormula("=if(ISBLANK(N2),"","Yes")");
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Perhaps you should review JavaScript comparison operators

Comment: Your code currently asks "Does the active cell have a value" if the active cell is on a sheet named "Sheet 1" and in column 14. If it has no value, then column 16 (14 + 2) gets the value "YES". Note that `getValue()` and `getFormula()` do not necessarily give the same results for a cell.